# my php email is sending with anonymous@foo.com

Tags: php, email

I am sure I am missing something really simple here but I cant seem to figure out what is wrong with my php email function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $to = "mz@foo.com";
        $from = "mr@foo.com";
    $subject = "test";
    $message = "This email was registered at ". $users_email;
    $message .= " on ".date('l jS \o\n F Y h:i:s A');
            $headers = "";
            $headers = 'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n';
            $headers .= "From: $from \r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $from\r\n";
            $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Attached to this is a form that asks users to just ask their email address. It then uses this and reloads the page with the variable set and sets up the email. I have left the validation out of here but I have a validation function. It sends the email but always says the email is sent from anonymous@foo.com. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding "Return-path: $from\r\n" .

Shai.

Comment: could it be something with my php.ini file?

Comment: Did you try adding this header? It didn't do the job? It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have my headers set up in a slightly different way; try this:

```
$headers = "From: $from \r\n" .
"Reply-To: $from \r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

This works for me, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What SMTP server are you sending from? If via GMail, they are pretty adamant about having emails sent through their SMTP having the from address as the email you used to send.

No real way around it, as far as I know.